Can't fetch tiles from this WMTS service with GDAL WMTS Driver
Other WMTS Services from same Geoportal work fine with GDAL, but I can not get this one to work:
gdalwarp -overwrite D:\test_gdal\wmts_raster.xml D:\test_gdal\668_raster_1.jpeg -of jpeg -te 2132898.837269558 6946597.130556818 2152466.7165105636 6966165.009797822 -te_srs EPSG:3857 -t_srs EPSG:3857 -ts 256 256
produces this error:
Creating output file that is 256P x 256L.
0ERROR 4: D:\test_gdal\gdalwmscache\40597d5671ea7d2314fef50106ec5da6/d/dcb9ba01d
b1642971896452abdcfef34.png: No such file or directory
ERROR 1: GDALWMS: Unable to open downloaded block.
ERROR 1: GDALWMS: Unable to download block 29, 18.
URL: URL rejected: Malformed input to a URL function
  HTTP status code: 0, error: URL rejected: Malformed input to a URL function.
Add the HTTP status code to <ZeroBlockHttpCodes> to ignore this error (see http:
//www.gdal.org/frmt_wms.html).
ERROR 1: GDAL_WMS>, band 1: IReadBlock failed at X offset 29, Y offset 18: GDALW
MS: Unable to download block 29, 18.
URL: URL rejected: Malformed input to a URL function
  HTTP status code: 0, error: URL rejected: Malformed input to a URL function.
Add the HTTP status code to <ZeroBlockHttpCodes> to ignore this error (see http:
//www.gdal.org/frmt_wms.html).
ERROR 1: IReadBlock failed at X offset 0, Y offset 0: GDAL_WMS>, band 1: IReadBl
ock failed at X offset 29, Y offset 18: GDALWMS: Unable to download block 29, 18
.
URL: URL rejected: Malformed input to a URL function
  HTTP status code: 0, error: URL rejected: Malformed input to a URL function.
Add the HTTP status code to <ZeroBlockHttpCodes> to ignore this error (see http:
//www.gdal.org/frmt_wms.html).

This is a working GetTile request:
http://mapy.geoportal.gov.pl/wss/service/WMTS/guest/wmts/TOPO?service=WMTS&request=GetTile&version=1.0.0&layer=MAPA%20TOPOGRAFICZNA&style=default&format=image/png&TileMatrixSet=EPSG:2180&TileMatrix=EPSG:2180:6&TileRow=21&TileCol=30&rfh=1&VERSION=1.0.0&TILEMATRIX=EPSG:2180
This is my WMTS-XML file:
<GDAL_WMTS>
  <GetCapabilitiesUrl>https://mapy.geoportal.gov.pl/wss/service/WMTS/guest/wmts/TOPO?SERVICE=WMTS&amp;REQUEST=GetCapabilities</GetCapabilitiesUrl>
  <Layer>MAPA TOPOGRAFICZNA</Layer>
  <ExtraQueryParameters>&amp;rfh=1&amp;VERSION=1.0.0&amp;TILEMATRIX=EPSG:2180</ExtraQueryParameters>
  <Style>default</Style>
  <TileMatrixSet>EPSG:2180</TileMatrixSet>
  <InfoFormat>text/html</InfoFormat>
  <Format>image/png</Format>
  <DataWindow>
    <UpperLeftX>118322.1678942625</UpperLeftX>
    <UpperLeftY>806302.1230210875</UpperLeftY>
    <LowerRightX>896351.9177006499</LowerRightX>
    <LowerRightY>116649.4687185375</LowerRightY>
  </DataWindow>
  <BandsCount>3</BandsCount>
  <DataType>Byte</DataType>
  <UserAgent>"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64; rv:109.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/115.0"</UserAgent>
  <Referer>https://mapy.geoportal.gov.pl/imap/Imgp_2.html?locale=pl&gui=new&sessionID=6332978</Referer>
  <Timeout>500</Timeout>
  <Cache>
  <Path>D:\test_gdal\gdalwmscache</Path>
  <Type>file</Type>
  <Depth>1</Depth>
  <Extension>.png</Extension>
  </Cache>  
  <UnsafeSSL>true</UnsafeSSL>
  <ZeroBlockHttpCodes>204,404</ZeroBlockHttpCodes>
  <ZeroBlockOnServerException>true</ZeroBlockOnServerException>
</GDAL_WMTS>

 gdalinfo wmts_raster.xml shows me this:
D:\\test_gdal\>gdalinfo wmts_raster.xml
Driver: WMTS/OGC Web Map Tile Service
Files: wmts_raster.xml
Size is 2915620, 2606556
Coordinate System is:
PROJCRS\["ETRF2000-PL / CS92",
BASEGEOGCRS\["ETRF2000-PL",
DATUM\["ETRF2000 Poland",
ELLIPSOID\["GRS 1980",6378137,298.257222101,
LENGTHUNIT\["metre",1\]\]\],
PRIMEM\["Greenwich",0,
ANGLEUNIT\["degree",0.0174532925199433\]\],
ID\["EPSG",9702\]\],
CONVERSION\["Poland CS92",
METHOD\["Transverse Mercator",
ID\["EPSG",9807\]\],
PARAMETER\["Latitude of natural origin",0,
ANGLEUNIT\["degree",0.0174532925199433\],
ID\["EPSG",8801\]\],
PARAMETER\["Longitude of natural origin",19,
ANGLEUNIT\["degree",0.0174532925199433\],
ID\["EPSG",8802\]\],
PARAMETER\["Scale factor at natural origin",0.9993,
SCALEUNIT\["unity",1\],
ID\["EPSG",8805\]\],
PARAMETER\["False easting",500000,
LENGTHUNIT\["metre",1\],
ID\["EPSG",8806\]\],
PARAMETER\["False northing",-5300000,
LENGTHUNIT\["metre",1\],
ID\["EPSG",8807\]\]\],
CS\[Cartesian,2\],
AXIS\["northing (x)",north,
ORDER\[1\],
LENGTHUNIT\["metre",1\]\],
AXIS\["easting (y)",east,
ORDER\[2\],
LENGTHUNIT\["metre",1\]\],
USAGE\[
SCOPE\["Topographic mapping (medium and small scale)."\],
AREA\["Poland - onshore and offshore."\],
BBOX\[49,14.14,55.93,24.15\]\],
ID\["EPSG",2180\]\]
Data axis to CRS axis mapping: 2,1
Origin = (124925.916518400001223,806302.123021087492816)
Pixel Size = (0.264583862500000,-0.264583862500000)
Metadata:
ABSTRACT=Warstwa prezentuj─àca rastrow─à map─Ö topograficzn─à
TITLE=MAPA TOPOGRAFICZNA
Image Structure Metadata:
INTERLEAVE=PIXEL
Corner Coordinates:
Upper Left  (  124925.917,  806302.123) ( 13d 8' 4.09"E, 54d58'42.16"N)
Lower Left  (  124925.917,  116649.469) ( 13d53'22.53"E, 48d48'14.46"N)
Upper Right (  896351.918,  806302.123) ( 25d11'46.21"E, 54d57'42.92"N)
Lower Right (  896351.918,  116649.469) ( 24d23'56.44"E, 48d47'26.96"N)
Center      (  510638.917,  461475.796) ( 19d 9'18.31"E, 52d 1' 9.78"N)
Band 1 Block=128x128 Type=Byte, ColorInterp=Red
Overviews: 1457810x1303278, 583124x521311, 291562x260656, 116625x104262, 58312
x52131, 29156x26066, 11662x10426, 5831x5213, 2916x2607, 1458x1303, 729x652, 364x
326
Band 2 Block=128x128 Type=Byte, ColorInterp=Green
Overviews: 1457810x1303278, 583124x521311, 291562x260656, 116625x104262, 58312
x52131, 29156x26066, 11662x10426, 5831x5213, 2916x2607, 1458x1303, 729x652, 364x
326
Band 3 Block=128x128 Type=Byte, ColorInterp=Blue
Overviews: 1457810x1303278, 583124x521311, 291562x260656, 116625x104262, 58312
x52131, 29156x26066, 11662x10426, 5831x5213, 2916x2607, 1458x1303, 729x652, 364x
326

Any ideas what might cause the error ??
